# Restart a process

Tags: c#, process, kill

I want to restart a program.
I've found the process and have called Kill method, then i've runned it again:
process.Kill();
process.Start();

It stops but doesn't start.
Also if I put Exited event it never fires.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Process.Kill()` is asynchronous.  You need to call `Process.WaitForExit()` after calling kill.

Comment: "Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided". Any clue?